# SQL Server Computer Column Using a Bit Column as the Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a computed column in SQL Server Management Studio off of a bit column but it keeps erroring out stating "Erro Validating the formula for column..."

I have tried the following:

```
CASE WHEN AribaSupplier_PotentialforCatalogFlag=1 THEN "True" ELSE "False" END
CASE WHEN AribaSupplier_PotentialforCatalogFlag='1' THEN "True" ELSE "False" END
CASE WHEN AribaSupplier_PotentialforCatalogFlag=True THEN "True" ELSE "False" END
CASE WHEN AribaSupplier_PotentialforCatalogFlag='True' THEN "True" ELSE "False" END
```

Comment: If this is SQL server you cant use double quotes.  and why convert a bit to true or false in your results?  thats what 1 and 0 are?

Comment: Thank you Brad I will try that. The reason I am creating a calculated column with text values off of a bit column is because I am creating a PowerApp and PowerApps unfortunately does not like to filter off of Bit columns in combination with other filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String constants should be in *single* quotes, not double quotes.  So try:

```
CASE WHEN AribaSupplier_PotentialforCatalogFlag = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is **SQL Server**, there is [IIF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
IIF(AribaSupplier_PotentialforCatalogFlag  = 1, 'True', 'False')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need single quote for string *constant* :

```
(CASE WHEN AribaSupplier_PotentialforCatalogFlag  = 1
      THEN 'true' ELSE 'false'
      WHEN AribaSupplier_PotentialforCatalogFlag = 'True' 
      THEN 'True' ELSE 'False'
 END)
```